# CypherQuery returns empty result in JavaEmbedded, but correct result in Neoclipse

Tags: neo4j, resultset, cypher, graph-databases

I have a strange problem with a cypher query. The query works fine in Neoclipse and returns the correct result. But in java embedded mode the result is empty. I can't figure out the problem. Is there a query character limit in java embedded or anything similar?

Here is the cypher query:

```
    START 
    typeNode6=node(6) ,
    containerNode=node(9) ,
    typeNode35=node(35) ,
    typeNode15=node(15) ,
    typeNode18=node(18) ,
    typeNode33=node(33) 
    MATCH (node6)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode6) ,
    (containerNode)-[:CONTAINS*]->(node6) ,
    (node35)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode35) ,
    (node6)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#actors`]->(node35) ,
    (node15)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode15) , 
    (node35)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#impersonatedBy`]->(node15) ,
    (node18)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode18) , 
    (node15)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/common#namedBy`]->(node18) ,
    (node33)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode33) , 
    (node6)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#runtime`]->(node33)  
    WHERE 
    node6.`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#releaseYear`! = 1988 
AND node18.`http://www.test.test/types/common#firstName`! = 'Robert' 
AND node18.`http://www.test.test/types/common#lastName`! = 'Davi' 
AND node33.`http://www.test.test/types/common#intValue`! = 131 RETURN node6";
```

Here is my java test-class:

```
@Test
    public void queryExecute() {
        ExecutionResult result, result2;
        ExecutionEngine engine;
        String query = "START typeNode6=node(6) ,containerNode=node(9) ,typeNode35=node(35) ,typeNode15=node(15) ,typeNode18=node(18) MATCH (node6)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode6) ,(containerNode)-[:CONTAINS*]->(node6) ,(node35)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode35) , (node6)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#actors`]->(node35) ,(node15)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode15) , (node35)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#impersonatedBy`]->(node15) ,(node18)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode18) , (node15)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/common#namedBy`]->(node18)  WHERE node18.`http://www.test.test/types/common#firstName`! = 'Robert' AND node18.`http://www.test.test/types/common#lastName`! = 'Davi' RETURN node6";
        String query2 = "START typeNode6=node(6) ,containerNode=node(9) ,typeNode35=node(35) ,typeNode15=node(15) ,typeNode18=node(18) ,typeNode33=node(33) MATCH (node6)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode6) ,(containerNode)-[:CONTAINS*]->(node6) ,(node35)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode35) , (node6)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#actors`]->(node35) ,(node15)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode15) , (node35)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#impersonatedBy`]->(node15) ,(node18)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode18) , (node15)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/common#namedBy`]->(node18) ,(node33)-[:TYPE]->(typeNode33) , (node6)-[:`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#runtime`]->(node33)  WHERE node6.`http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#releaseYear`! = 1988 AND node18.`http://www.test.test/types/common#firstName`! = 'Robert' AND node18.`http://www.test.test/types/common#lastName`! = 'Davi' AND node33.`http://www.test.test/types/common#intValue`! = 131 RETURN node6";
        engine = new ExecutionEngine(svrInstance.getNeoGraphdb());
        result = engine.execute(query);
        result2 = engine.execute(query2);
        Assert.assertNotNull(result);

        System.out.println("============== CYPHER QUERY TEST ==============");
        System.out.println("uncomplicated: ");
        System.out.println(result.toString());
        System.out.println("complicated: ");
        System.out.println(result2.toString());
        System.out.println("============== CYPHER QUERY TEST ==============");

    }
```

And this is the output from the java console:

```
============== CYPHER QUERY TEST ==============
uncomplicated: 
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| node6                                                                                                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[7]{http://www.test.test/types/common#id:"movie_1",http://www.test.test/types/s3/media#releaseYear:1988,type:"instance",instanceId:"movie_1"} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row
138 ms

complicated: 
+-------+
| node6 |
+-------+
+-------+
0 row
4 ms

============== CYPHER QUERY TEST ==============
```

Both queries (in java) should return the same result (At least in Neoclipse). The difference is that the "complicated query" got more "WHERE" conditions.

By the way the queries are generated dynamically from java, but this shouldn't be the problem, because they work in Neoclipse. (And I always used the same database location.)

Thank you for helping!
Greetings Max

Comment: What neo4j version are you using in Neoclipse/Java embedded?

Comment: In Java embedded: `    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
      <classifier>static-web</classifier>
      <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>` and Neoclipse 1.8

Comment: Can you publish a small example java project that exhibits this problem in order to test it out?

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you for helping. Is there any chance to share the project privatley? I can't post the test-Database here. I set up a MavenProject with the necessary code and I included the test-Database. Greetings Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I could figure out, that both queries work fine with Neo4jServer Version 1.7.2.
Something must be wrong with Version 1.8.2!!

Comment: And in Version 1.9.RC1 it's also working! So it seems to be that the problem is solved in the next version.